# how to delete temp files which is created by google chrome in linux?

Tags: google-chrome

I want clean up cache file or row data which is created by the Google chrome during playing video's form youtube as well as other site task.
During cleanup I want to protect my history and cookies.

Where does Google chrome store cache data in Linux?

Is it possible that we manually delete cache files of Google chrome?
But during delete that files we at least save our browsers history.

Note:- I am using standard account privilege.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use Chrome's "Delete" functions to achieve this?  Is there a reason you don't want to use that deletion function which lets you select what to destroy?

Comment: All cache is saved under ~/.cache/google-chrome

Comment: @ThomasW.  if I use chrome://settings/ or chrome://history/ there is options for clear history but not for junk files. I want **protect my browsers history** for quick remember or access files.

Comment: Better use **incognito mode**. This is what chrome will tell you if you use it's delete history feature...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Normally Google Chrome save this temporary files inside:

```
~/.cache/google-chrome/[profile]/Cache/
```

and

```
~/.config/google-chrome/[profile]/Application Cache/Cache/
```

And yes you can delete these manually and you don't need any permission.

So just take a look at these dirs and choose what to delete

Another interesting directory is

```
~/.config/google-chrome/Default
```

Here you find your history , bookmarks , extensions, ....

so choose carefuly what do you want to purge

---

UPDATE:

The bookmark is not really a directory it's just a file. The path to this file is:

```
~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Bookmarks
```

The history also is not a file, it's some sqlite3 database file under this path

```
~/.config/google-chrome/Default/History
```

A simple tip:

```
nautilus ~/.config/google-chrome/Default
```

will open the directory so just take some time and check all of files found there, you can easily know what to keep or what to delete

Comment: Your ans is very useful for deleting media cache which are not generally clear by browser.

Comment: Can You provide exact which folder should not delete for protect 1) History and 2) Book Marks. then Your answers is perfect and Ultimate.

Comment: I'll edit my answer wait me a second